# SCP over SSH with no password - cannot get it to work

Tags: ssh, scp

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server with SSH, I have configured a keypair so I can SSH on to a remote system with no password, this works fine.

I am trying to SCP from Local (system1) to ther remote (system2), the SCP works fine but asks for a password. I want to use the keypair for non-autheticated copying.

I have followed numerous guides from the web on how to do this, but it basically seems to boils down to the following:

```
scp -i <path the PRIVATE key file>  filetocopy  user@remote.co.uk:~
```

Everything I can find on the internet says this should work - but it keeps asking for the password for the remote (2nd) system, even though I know the keypair works OK because I can use it for SSH.

Annoyingly - the same command as above will work perfectly with no password request if run as root - either by way of 'sudo' or from an elevated terminal...

so:

```
sudo scp -i <path the PRIVATE key file>  filetocopy  user@remote.co.uk:~
```

Works fine, but:

```
scp -i <path the PRIVATE key file>  filetocopy  user@remote.co.uk:~
```

does not.

There are no files in the roots' .ssh folder except for the known_hosts files (i.e. no key files)

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have copied the `root` key to the remote server, while the regular user key wasn't copied correctly.

`ssh` and `scp` should provide the same feedback (with the difference of login-into-remote-server vs. copy-file-into-remote-server)

When the key-pair will be copied as required to the remote server, the `scp` command will be:

```
scp local-file-name user@remote-host:/full/path/remote-file-name
```

---

**In order to copy the user key to the remote server, you can use** [ssh-copy-id](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id)

> Note: You should replace the *mykey* in the below command, with the
>   filename of your key-file

**Copy the key to a server**

Once an SSH key has been created, the ssh-copy-id command can be used to install it as an authorized key on the server. Once the key has been authorized for SSH, it grants access to the server without a password.

Use a command like the following to copy SSH key:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/mykey user@host
```

This logs into the server host, and copies keys to the server, and configures them to grant access by adding them to the authorized_keys file. The copying may ask for a password or other authentication for the server.

Only the public key is copied to the server. The private key should never be copied to another machine.

**Test the new key**

Once the key has been copied, it is best to test it:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey user@host
```

The login should now complete without asking for a password. Note, however, that the command might ask for the passphrase you specified for the key.
Troubleshooting

Comment: The following links and links from them might be helpful, https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH

Comment: Hello - thanks for your suggestion. I tried this but it did not work - the root does not have anys set up on it.   I did the ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/mykey user@host command, i said it had copied over the keys correctly but the problems ipersists.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do these following things to do scp over ssh without password:

```
ssh-keygen
[Enter]
[Enter]
[Enter]
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub username@serverip/hostname
scp username@serverip:/file/to/copy /directory/to/save
```

This will work, if you got any error please update.

Answer (score 0):

I got this sorted - I removed all my keys and keyfiles from both systems and worked through the process of setting up new keyfiles and using ssh-copy-id to copy the files over.
It now works great.

There must have been some obscure corruption in the authorizes_keys file maybe messing it up.
Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) You can also 'accept' one answer and 'upvote' the helpful answers.